# Java Executors not queue some task

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, executorservice

I couldn't find any executors that fulfill my requirement.
I want to have an ExecutorService with corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize and with BlockingQueue;

When execute function is called, like usual, use core thread, if core threads are in use, then put the task to the queue and if queue is full then create new thread until reaches maximumPoolSize. this is the standard behavior for ThreaPoolExecutor.
[ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#getActiveCount--)

Everyhing is okey until this part. I can create a ThreadPoolExecutor with this specification.

But for some task, don't queue them create a new thread if core thread is full. But if maximumPoolSize reach then queue the task but put the task first.

How can I implement such a requirement, is there any built-in functionality that I can use.

Comment: What does this mean? "...then queue the task but put the task first."

Comment: You want tasks prioritized so last task submitted is the first task to be scheduled next for execution? [LIFO](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type))?

Comment: @BasilBourque yes but for some task only, like calling executeNow() function for them, if maxPoolSize is not full then use them otherwise put the task to the top of the queue.

Comment: Which criteria is supposed to tell the executor that a certain task is the special task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I know of no executor service that prioritizes tasks to be run ahead of other tasks.

## Multiple executor services

But you can effectively do that yourself quite easily. Establish multiple executor services. Use one for the low priority tasks, and another for the high priority tasks.

In the following example, we assume a 12-core machine that is not over-burdened. We assign a thousand tasks to the low priority service. And we assign three tasks to the high priority service. The three important tasks will be scheduled for execution immediately.

```
ExecutorService highPriorityExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 5 ) ;
ExecutorService lowPriorityExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 3 ) ;
```

---

By the way, [Project Loom](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/loom/Main) may make moot your issue, if that team succeeds. Performance may be so dramatically improved that in some scenarios your need to prioritize tasks may evaporate.

Project Loom adds [virtual threads](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/8277131) (a.k.a [fibers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_(computer_science))) to the concurrency facilities of Java. Virtual threads run so cheaply, with more efficient use of memory and CPU, that a common computer may be able to handle millions of threads.

The [JVM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) schedules the many virtual threads onto a few “real” threads managed by the host operating system. Any virtual thread whose work blocks is instantly set aside (“parked”), as another virtual thread is scheduled for immediate execution. The underlying carrier threads, the host OS threads, do not block in such cases. The goal is to keep the host threads constantly working productively whenever any virtual threads are pending.

Experimental builds of OpenJDK with Project Loom technology are available now, based on early-access Java 18.

Comment: You probably mean “based on early-access Java 18”. But virtual threads alone won’t prioritize tasks. It would still require a construct that blocks certain tasks as long as tasks with higher priority exist (and run).

Comment: @Holger Yes, I meant 18; thank you, fixed. As for virtual threads, not they do not directly provide prioritization of tasks. What I meant is that performance may be so dramatically improved that in some scenarios the need to prioritize may evaporate.

Comment: This applies if the tasks are potentially blocking (I/O etc). Then, the need to limit the number of threads disappears with Loom, as the virtual threads cooperate. For computational intense tasks, it still makes a difference, which tasks consume CPU time…

Comment: @Holger True, but I expect CPU-bound Java-based apps that make no network calls, no database calls, no logging, and no file access in storage, to be quite rare. Such apps would then use the existing concurrency features already found in Java, such as the pair of high/low-priority executor services shown in this Answer.